# node.js not functioning correctly, windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    httpServer = http.createServer(app);

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', 3000);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

httpServer.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port %s.", httpServer.address().port);
});
```

However this gives the follow errors:

```
C:\var\www\stage.mayfieldafc.com>nodemon http.js
18 Jul 01:19:29 - [nodemon] v1.2.1
18 Jul 01:19:29 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
18 Jul 01:19:29 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
18 Jul 01:19:29 - [nodemon] starting `node http.js`

C:\var\www\stage.mayfieldafc.com\http.js:8
app.configure(function () {
    ^
TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  } has no method 'configure'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\var\www\stage.mayfieldafc.com\http.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
18 Jul 01:19:29 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

After installing both `nodemon` and `express` and I can see both folders inside of `node_modules`

Also when console logging the return of `express` I see that it has correctly loaded the module.

How can I verify my node install? Or better still fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express 4 no longer has `app.configure()`. See [the wiki](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x) on migrating from Express 3 to Express 4.

Answer (score 1):

The method `app.configure` has been removed from `express 4`. So now you have to say something like bellow.

```
app.set('port', 3000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

instead of

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', 3000);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

and there are many other changes has been made.